# ¿Cómo puedo sumar las entradas de un solo input con Keyup?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentado sumar todo lo que trae un input, es decir por cada numero

que pongo en el input tiene que sumar, sin embargo no puedo lograrlo,

dentro del keyup mando a llamar la función para sumar.

Muestro mi código

```js
$.fn.delayPasteKeyUp = function(fn, ms)
{
    var timer = 0;
    $(this).on("propertychange input", function()
    {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(fn, ms);
    });
};

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#ingreso").delayPasteKeyUp(function(){
   $("#respuesta").append("Producto registrado: "+ $("#ingreso").val() +"<br>");
    $("#ingreso").val("");
}, 200);
sumar();
});

function sumar()
{
  const $total = document.getElementById('total');
  let subtotal = 0;
  [ ...document.getElementsByClassName( "ingreso" ) ].forEach( function ( element ) {
    if(element.value !== '') {
      subtotal += parseFloat(element.value);
    }
  });
  $total.value = subtotal;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js">  </script>
 
<input type="text" name="delay" id="ingreso" class="itemTotalNeto" autofocus onchange="sumar();"> 
<div id="respuesta"></div>
    
<span>TOTAL </span>
<input type="number" id="total" value="0" readonly/>
```

buena tarde amigos.

Estoy intentado sumar todo lo que trae un input, es decir por cada numero

que pongo en el input tiene que sumar, sin embargo no puedo lograrlo,

dentro del keyup mando a llamar la función para sumar.

Muestro mi código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es mi propuesta para resolver tu problema, a ver que te parece:

```js
$("#ingreso").on("propertychange input", function() {
  sumar();
  $("#respuesta").append("Producto registrado: " + $(this).val() + "<br>");
  $(this).val("");
});

function sumar() {
  const total = document.getElementById('total');
  $("#total").val(parseFloat($("#total").val()) + parseFloat($("#ingreso").val()))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js">  </script>
 
<input type="text" name="delay" id="ingreso" class="itemTotalNeto" autofocus> 
<div id="respuesta"></div>
    
<span>TOTAL </span>
<input type="number" id="total" value="0" readonly/>
```

Como ves, he reducido tu código a la mínima expresión, porque tenias cosas que sobraban para realizar esta tarea más específica.

**Explicación de los cambios:**

1. He cambiado el orden de la función `sumar()` y lo he puesto al principio despues de llamar al evento `propertychange input` del campo con id `ingreso` porque si lo dejaba donde estaba su valor era 0, pues en tu código eliminabas su `value` antes de llamar a la suma.
2. He usado `$(this)` en lugar de `$(#ingreso)` dentro de la captura del evento para dejarlo más limpio y claro. No hacia falta tanta redundancia cuando el `$(this)` ya representa al objeto llamado dentro de la función.
3. He reducido la función **sumar()** a la minima expresión, dejando el sumatorio deseado en esta línea:

```
$("#total").val(parseFloat($("#total").val()) + parseFloat($("#ingreso").val()))
```

La cual asigna al elemento `total` el valor resultante de sumar su valor actual (`parseFloat($("#total").val())`) al nuevo valor contenido en el elemento con el id **ingreso** (`parseFloat($("#ingreso").val()`).

Comprueba si te funciona como esperabas pulsando sobre ejecutar y agregando números al input y nos cuentas.

Comment: muchas gracias, tienes razón tenia redundancia en el objeto this